Symbology style from SIGEOM database to QGIS with correct legend
I am having an issue with having the correct colors for my map and these colors being in accordance with my legend.
I imported a shp from SIGEOM database in QGIS. When I click on categorized in the control feature symbology using as value the lithology descriptions, I get all the different random colors from qgis. Hovewer, I want to import the colors that sigeom is using for their map. I downloaded this file from their database and I loaded the style and the colors are exactly as they sigeom map, which is great and looks like that:

however, in the control feature symbology now it looks like that after I loaded the sigeom style:

The problem is now that I want to print the map with the legend showing the different lithologies, but now it shows the code_symbol as shown in the picture. How can I solve this and have the correct colors based on the lithologies?
Also, the attribute table from the shp looks like that:

I also tried to use the RGB colors shown on the attribute table to have the right colors but then I have the same issue of not having the lithologies in my legend.
